# Cannot Generate PDFs using Tree.io (Django and Apache)

Tags: django, pdf, mod-wsgi, treeio-django

I have installed Tree.io using [this tutorial](http://www.makeyouadmin.com/2014/04/install-treeio-on-ubuntu-with-apache-mysql.html#.U-Z3JnVJXUa):

Tree.io is installed in /home/treeio/treeio

The Folder belongs to www-data:www-data with chmod rwxrwxr-x

Whenever I try to generate a PDF, I get this error (Some URLs Blanked out for Security Reasons):

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://office.mydomain.de/contacts/contact/view/75.pdf

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django_websocket',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'treeio.account',
 'treeio.core',
 'treeio.core.api',
 'treeio.core.search',
 'treeio.documents',
 'treeio.events',
 'treeio.finance',
 'treeio.identities',
 'treeio.infrastructure',
 'treeio.knowledge',
 'treeio.messaging',
 'treeio.news',
 'treeio.projects',
 'treeio.reports',
 'treeio.sales',
 'treeio.services',
 'dajaxice',
 'dajax',
 'coffin',
 'captcha',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.user.AuthMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.user.LanguageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
 'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.user.SSLMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.chat.ChatAjaxMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.modules.ModuleDetect',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.user.CommonMiddleware',
 'treeio.core.middleware.user.PopupMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/treeio/treeio/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  121.                             response = middleware_method(request, e)
File "/home/treeio/treeio/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/treeio/treeio/core/decorators.py" in wrap
  124.                 response = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/treeio/treeio/core/decorators.py" in wrap
  48.                         return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/treeio/treeio/identities/views.py" in contact_view
  403.                               context_instance=RequestContext(request), response_format=response_format)
File "/home/treeio/treeio/core/rendering.py" in render_to_response
  181.         f = open(output)

Exception Type: IOError at /contacts/contact/view/75.pdf
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/treeio/treeio/static/media/pdfs/174ce9c2e1ac29733db566275c5eb76b'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue - been scratching my head for hours on this and still cannot fathom it out.

I can however submit the suggestion to sudo service apache2 reload after every change.

E